# SQL How to select max value when comparing 2 sql tables

Tags: sql, max

I am working on a project and I am stuck on a Query:

I want to create some kind of GPS based on wi-fi.
There are 2 tables (users and locations) and I need to put results in a third table.

First table is where info from users phones is sent.

Phone MAC address and Wireless Access Points MACs with signal strength. Users phones can see more than one wireless access point.

Second table is where all known wireless Access Points with their coordinates (Latitude and Longitude) are stored.

Here are the tables:

`Users`:

```
| PhoneMac    |   apMac      |   signal  |  
|   user1     |11:11:11      |     20    |  
|   user1     |22:22:22      |     80    |  
|   user1     |33:33:33      |     50    |  
|   user1     |55:55:55      |     99    |  
|   user2     |11:11:11      |     60    |  
|   user3     |44:44:44      |     10    |  
|   user3     |11:11:11      |     90    |
```

`Locations` table:

```
| apMac           |   Lat       |   Lon     |  
|   11:11:11      |10.000       |30.000     |  
|   33:33:33      |30.000       |30.000     |  
|   44:44:44      |40.000       |40.000     |
```

I need a query that takes apMac from `Users` table, check whether they are in `Locations` table and from those found choose the one with strongest signal.

So results should be PhoneMac and coordinates of chosen AP. It should be done with every user.

Using the tables above this should be the correct result:

```
| PhoneMac     |     Lat     |     Lon       |  
|   user1      |30.000       |30.000         |  
|   user2      |10.000       |10.000         |  
|   user3      |10.000       |10.000         |  

    sql = "SELECT t1.PhoneMac, t1.apMac, t1.signal, t2.apMac, t2.lat, t2.lon,
    COUNT(t1.MacTel) AS num
    FROM users t1
    INNER JOIN locations t2
    ON t1.apMac=t2.apMac
    GROUP BY t1.PhoneMac
    ORDER BY num DESC";
```

This is the code I have so far. I can't figure out how to include part about selecting `apMac` with strongest signal, because now it only returns the first `apMac` from the list.

Comment: What database system is this for? *SQL* is just the query language - not a database product ...

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select PhoneMac, lat, long
from (select u.PhoneMac, l.lat, l.long,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by u.apMac order by signal desc) as seqnum
      from users u join
           locations l
           on u.apMac = l.apMac
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In MySQL or Access or some other database that doesn't support the ANSI standard `row_number()`, you can do this with correlated subqueries.  here is one way:

```
select distinct PhoneMac,
        (select lat from Locations l where l.apMac = u.apMac order by signal limit 1) as lat,
        (select lon from Locations l where l.apMac = u.apMac order by signal limit 1) as long
from users u
```